# Sharing a drive folder after payment

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm trying to set up a system where people can buy an informational video product. I'm hosting the videos in a Google Drive folder. I'd like to know how I could automate a system where people buy the product through my website, and their email address is invited to view the folder.

Comment: Do you have the ability and access to add/modify code on your website? If so, you'd need to add some event that's fired/called when a purchase has been made and successful, grabs the provided email, and then calls a Google rest API to perform the desired function.

Answer (score 0):

1. I'd recommend not just sharing out a single file with every customer, that will leak the users list out
2. Your easiest option is just to make it `read with link` and email them that link when they pay; no access list to worry about, and anyone who could leak out the link could also just leak the video